# passing header in post method to access token

Tags: python, post

I am trying to pass header in post method for generating access token. however I am getting the wrror about invalid syntax. my header code is as below

```
headers=("Authorization: Basic RXadsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdjkfhsuidhsuihf==","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

headers=('Authorization': 'Basic RXadsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdjkfhsuidhsuihf==','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `Requests`, headers should be a dictionary, so:

```
headers={
    "Authorization": "Basic RXadsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdjkfhsuidhsuihf==",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try the below code:**

```
auth_token = "Basic {}".format(token)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': auth_token}
```